# C# Web App question

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

Im working on an web app using c#. I have in my code the following timer that checks for a file on a server:

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image1.Visible = false;


            if (File.Exists(@"\\server/money/Folder2/RAW.xls"))
                //inform user
                Label2.Visible = true;

            else
            {
                Label2.Visible = false;
                Label3.Visible = true;
            }

            if (File.Exists(@"\\server/money/Folder2/RAW.xls"))
                //inform user
                Image2.Visible = true;
            else
            {
                Image2.Visible = false;
                Image3.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Heres my issue. On the local machine and even within ther server everything checks out, the systems see the file and bam, pretty graphic and text is shown saying yup file is there.... BUT when I load the app on another machine [laptop or workstation] its like it doesnt see the file. It load the page just fine but is gives me the bad image and text saying file not found.  Using IIS 7.5, everything is default for the most part execpt im using ASP 4.0. Does anyone have any insight to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me guess, you are debugging locally with Cassini (the built in web server), but then publish to IIS and it doesn't work there? If so, then its a permission issue - IIS AppPool doesn't have permission for the network path.

Comment: Thanks... So how would I configure that in Windows 08? Sorry Im new to this here.

Comment: you can i.e. create an AppPool with a new identity, just create a new AppPool `Foo`, set the user identity to a user that has access to the share\network path and then set you web app to run under that AppPool. All of that can be done within the IIS management console

Comment: OK sweetness, Ill give that a try and see if that works. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind with a scenario like this is permissions.  By default, the account that IIS runs under doesn't have permission to access network resources.